# What is the simplest way to dump this column copy of excel data into a python numpy array?

Tags: python, excel, numpy

Need to do some filtering today.  Since it would have taken me at least an hour in excel I decided learn how to do it in python in about 30 seconds.  The hardest part is pasting the data column from excel (a string with carriage return separated values?) into python.  In matlab I could do this sort of thing, but in python I suspect I need to maybe put quotations around it and use a simple \n parser or regex?  Thanks for the help!

```
import scipy
import numpy
from scipy import signal

N=10
Fc=0.1
Fs=1.14

h=scipy.signal.firwin(N, Fc, Fs/2)

x = [23.57734807
24.6558011
23.60110497
25.6801105
24.75524862
23.70055249
23.50718232
23.56906077
22.82265193
23.78563536
21.47348066
22.15359116]
```

I get this error:

```
    24.6558011
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what is x in your question?

Comment: x is a snippet of my signal vector   ... just a column of numbers from excel

Comment: I mean how does it become x = [.. etc..?

Comment: @user391339 - Do you intend to apply a `fir` filter to that signal `x`? It's not quite clear on what you want to do here so far.

Comment: x is a column cut from excel and pasted into my python editor ...   i am pretty sure it is a string when it is pasted.  i tried surrounding it by python '''long''' quotes and working on getting regex or string.replace to give me something i can work with matlab style

Comment: was thinking of something like data.replace("\n", ",")    then    [data] to get the comma separated values in the list

Comment: OK, I wasn't told that's what you're trying to do.  I wasn't aware that you are copying and pasting that column as a string.  In that case, the answer by @PadraicCunningham is most acceptable, as it will delimit each number then create a Python list out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what  the data inside `x` is  but if it is a string, you can use `str.split`:

```
import numpy as np



s = """23.57734807
24.6558011
23.60110497
25.6801105
24.75524862
23.70055249
23.50718232
23.56906077
22.82265193
23.78563536
21.47348066
22.15359116
"""
x  = s.split()
print x
print np.array(x,dtype=float)

['23.57734807', '24.6558011', '23.60110497', '25.6801105', '24.75524862', '23.70055249',   '23.50718232', '23.56906077', '22.82265193', '23.78563536', '21.47348066', '22.15359116']

[ 23.57734807  24.6558011   23.60110497  25.6801105   24.75524862
23.70055249  23.50718232  23.56906077  22.82265193  23.78563536
21.47348066  22.15359116]
```

As per your comment that is is all a string, use `str.replace` and with `split`:

```
import numpy as np

x = """[23.57734807
24.6558011
23.60110497
25.6801105
24.75524862
23.70055249
23.50718232
23.56906077
22.82265193
23.78563536
21.47348066
22.15359116]
"""

 arr = np.array(x.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(),dtype=float)
 print arr

[ 23.57734807  24.6558011   23.60110497  25.6801105   24.75524862
23.70055249  23.50718232  23.56906077  22.82265193  23.78563536
21.47348066  22.15359116]
```

Comment: +1 - You managed to figure out what the OP wanted before the OP lol.

Answer (score 1):

You need `,` commas in your list

```
x = [23.57734807,
24.6558011,
23.60110497,
25.6801105,
24.75524862,
23.70055249,
23.50718232,
23.56906077,
22.82265193,
23.78563536,
21.47348066,
22.15359116]
```

Comment: Wow... almost 40 seconds off of each other lol. Nice.  I wouldn't have answered if I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to represent your signal as a Python list.  As such, you need to delineate each item in `x` by a comma if that's the case.  In other words, you would need to do:

```
x = [23.57734807, 24.6558011, 23.60110497, 25.6801105, 24.75524862, 
     23.70055249, 23.50718232, 23.56906077, 22.82265193, 23.78563536, 
     21.47348066, 22.15359116]
```

In MATLAB, you don't need to place commas between each number as each element can either be comma or space delimited, but for Python lists, you need the comma.